# How to set Summernote editor's width in percentage

Tags: javascript, html, summernote

Now I'm using Summernote text editor. Is there any way to set its width and height in percentage? Unfortunately, I can't find any answer at all.

```
editor.summernote({
    //buttons in toolbar
    toolbar: [
        ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
        ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
        ['fontsize', ['fontname', 'fontsize', 'style']],
        ['color', ['color']],
        ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
        ['height', ['height']],
        ['table', ['table']],
        ['customButton', ['equation']],
        ['util', ['undo', 'redo']],
    ],
    // prevents copying of text formattion from an external resource
    callbacks: {
        onPaste: function (e) {
            var bufferText = ((e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('Text');
            e.preventDefault();
            document.execCommand('insertText', false, bufferText);

        }
    },

    buttons: {
        equation: equationButton
    },
    toolbarContainer: '#editorToolbar',
    placeholder: 'Type Here',
    height: 200,
    width: 200, //  - >   **something like 40% ?**
});
```

Thank you for any answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can set the width via CSS on the `.note-editor` class, if you need to do both the width and height as percentage then CSS only won't cut it then you can set the width via CSS and the height with something like:

```
$('.note-editor').height($(window).height()* 0.4)); sets it to 40% of screen height.
```